# There is $f$ nonnilpotent in $A[[x]]$ with nilpotent coefficients -- solution verification

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, nilpotence, formal-power-series

This is an exercise in Atiyah-MacDonald (Exercise 5.2). I have shown that if $f \in A[[x]]$ ($A$ commutative with unity) is nilpotent, then $f$'s coefficients are all nilpotent. The next question in the exercise is: "Is the converse true?"

I think not, but it would be wonderful if someone else could check my solution. I'm aware that there are solutions elsewhere, but I'm trying to avoid looking at those.

---

Let $A = \mathbf{Z}[z_2,z_3,\dots]/I$, where $I = (z_i^2 : 2 \leq i < \infty)$. Further define $z_0 = z_1 = 0$; clearly every element of $\{z_i\}_{i=0}^\infty$ is nilpotent. Now define $f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty z_ix^i$.

Let $N = \sum_{i=3}^{k-2} i = {k-1 \choose 2} - 3$. Then after expanding, the coefficient of $x^N$ in $f^k$ is:

$${ N \choose 1, 1,\dots,1} z_3z_4\dots z_{q-2} + \sum(\cdots)$$

where $\sum(\cdots)$ is the remaining terms. Since ${N \choose 1,\dots,1} \neq 0$ and $z_3z_4\dots z_{q-2} \neq 0$, it follows that the coefficient of $x^N$ in $f^k$ is nonzero, hence $f^k \neq 0$. This construction holds for every $k \in \mathbf{N}$, so $f$ is not nilpotent.

Comment: Please *do* search for dupes before asking in order to avoid asking duplicate questions.

Comment: Generally, for a `solution-verification` question to be on topic you must specify *precisely* which step in the proof you question, and *why so*. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.